# How to install ghost (blog) as npm module in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, installation, ghost

I have installed ghost as npm module via "meteor npm install ghost --save" in my windows 10 console.  I develop my app on my local machine and I use meteor-up once I'm finished to upload the project to my site.

How do I install ghost via an npm module?  I can't find a guide specifically for that, all the other guides are for Ghost CLI or other methods of install, I don't want to mess up my install.

I also want the ghost blog as a subdirectory, for example: mysite.com/blog

Comment: "I don't want to mess up my install" - Do you use a cvs like git or svn? If so, why not create a new branch and see, if things mess up?

Comment: Sure, I can fork a branch, the main thing is how to get ghost running, I'm new to ghost and relatively new to meteor as well.  Do I need mySQL on my local machine for a local ghost install as well?  I want it as a subdirectory as mentioned.

Comment: I think you will then have less trouble when you create your ghost blog as an own nodejs app and run it as you already described as a sub route /blog next to your meteor app.

Comment: The question is, how do I install it as an nodejs app within meteor, meteor just recently started it's own npm module function, and there are no guides whatsoever on it.  I'm pretty new at both, even to coding in Javascript.  It seems really complicated to just get running.  Anybody know any guides or what the first step is in installing ghost as an npm module in meteor?